# PHP not toggling

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
if ($row['locked'] == 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET locked=1 WHERE id='".$topic_id."'") or die('not working');
}
if ($row['locked'] == 1){
    mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET locked=0 WHERE id='".$topic_id."'") or die('not working');
}
```

It's supposed to toggle locked but it's only setting it to 1. Not the other way around.

Why?

Comment: What is the value of `$row['locked']`? Also, [possibly relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: also you should use mysqli instead of mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just do:

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET locked = NOT locked WHERE id='".$topic_id."'") or die('not working');
```

Which will toggle the `locked` column directly and you won't need the `if` statements.

Comment: Wow. That worked perfectly! I had no idea that exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*why*?

Because `$row['locked']` is equal to zero.

Simply set `$row['locked'] = 1;`

Before your control statement.

Comment: how do you know that `$row['locked']` is equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Btw where do you get your `$row['locked']` from? Share more code.

Why dont you just include your variable inside the query instead of writing the conditional statements?

For example:

```
$updateTo=!$row['locked'];

$query = "UPDATE questions SET locked='$updateTo' WHERE id='$topic_id'";
```

P.S. Start using `mysqli` or `PDO` prepared statements instead of old, deprecated `mysql_query`.

---

**Or to just solve your problem:**

Set your `$row['locked']` to **1**;

This will for example trigger action with button click.

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$row['locked'] = 1;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='post' />
</form>
```